# Laplace transform of function's derivative

Tags: laplace-transform

As stated in wikipedia:

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_{0^-}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$
$$=\left[\frac{f(t)e^{-st}}{-s}\right]_{0^-}^{\infty}-\int_{0^-}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}f'(t)dt\space,\space\space\space(by\space parts)$$
$$=\left[-\frac{f(0^-)}{-s}\right]+\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$$

Note that from the second line to the third, it's assumed that $t\to\infty$ makes the first term go to zero. Shouldn't this be specified only if $Re(s)>0$ and if $f(t)$ grows less than $e^{-st}$?

Comment: It is *assumed* that $\rm{Re}\,s>0$ and that $f(t)$ most is of exponential growth.

Comment: When and why is that assumed? So there is a limit whether I can use this derivative rule?

Comment: When one introduces the Laplace transform, it is not defined for all *possible* functions, only for those that do not grow faster than exponents. Moreover, very often additional requirements on $s$ are necessary, such as ${\rm Re}\,s>a,$ where $a$ some constant. After this is defined, these things are not mentioned anymore.

Comment: Ain't $Re(s)$ valid for all real numbers and we only limit based on the region of convergence?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: Can't I have a laplace transform of some function which its region of convergence includes negative values of the real part of $s$? Considering that, how this rule can be applied in such cases if there is a requirement which is $s>0$?

Comment: I give up. Sorry, cannot decipher what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should check again, but if, for instance, $f$ is a probability density function then the Laplace transform is well defined only if $e^{-st}f(t) \to 0$ for $t \to \infty$ which gives you line 3.